# Governor limits on http callouts

Tags: governorlimits

I am having to make a httpcallout from a VF page to get some data from an external source. 
I can see there is a limit of 10 callouts per transaction

> Total number of callouts (HTTP requests or Web services calls) in a transaction   10

What would a transaction mean? 
Assuming i am making a http request on click of a button and once the request is completed i again click the button, would this amount to 2 callouts in one transaction or would be considered as 2 different transactions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Salesforce provides a [decent explanation of transactions](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apex_workbook/Content/apex_transactions.htm):

> **What is an Apex Transaction?**
>
> An Apex transaction represents a set of operations that are executed
>   as a single unit. All DML operations in a transaction either complete
>   successfully, or if an error occurs in one operation, the entire
>   transaction is rolled back and no data is committed to the database.
>   The boundary of a transaction can be a trigger, a class method, an
>   anonymous block of code, a Visualforce page, or a custom Web service
>   method.
>
> All operations that occur inside the transaction boundary represent a
>   single unit of operations. This also applies for calls that are made
>   from the transaction boundary to external code, such as classes or
>   triggers that get fired as a result of the code running in the
>   transaction boundary. For example, consider the following chain of
>   operations: a custom Apex Web service method causes a trigger to fire,
>   which in turn calls a method in a class. In this case, all changes are
>   committed to the database only after all operations in the transaction
>   finish executing and don’t cause any errors. If an error occurs in any
>   of the intermediate steps, all database changes are rolled back and
>   the transaction isn’t committed.

So, to answer your original question, that will be treated as two transactions. Clicking a button to fire off a single call works as one transaction that will complete. When you click it again, it will be another transaction.